Bitcoind node is stuck
My node got stuck a week ago it was version 26 I updated to version 27 and re-downloaded whole chain. My node is stuck ant block 840959.
I tried reboot whole server.
I dont want to reindex all again, it will take a whole week again.
How I can solve this problem?
I dont know if this can be related but I also run lnd node.
Os: Ububtu 22.04
Hardware:
Intel Core i7-2600
HDD2x HDD SATA 3,0 TB
RAM4x RAM 4096 MB DDR3

Here is some info.
bitcoin-cli -getinfo

Chain: main
Blocks: 840959
Headers: 840959
Verification progress: 99.7043%
Difficulty: 88104191118793.16

Network: in 10, out 10, total 20
Version: 270000
Time offset (s): 0
Proxies: n/a
Min tx relay fee rate (BTC/kvB): 0.00000000

Warnings: (none)

log file:
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Bitcoin Core version v27.0 (release build)
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z InitParameterInteraction: parameter interaction: -externalip set -> setting -discover=0
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Script verification uses 7 additional threads
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Using the 'sse4(1way),sse41(4way)' SHA256 implementation
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Default data directory /root/.bitcoin
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Using data directory /home/btc_node_data
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Config file: /root/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Config file arg: daemon="1"
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Config file arg: datadir="/home/btc_node_data"
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Config file arg: externalip="*.*.*.*"
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Config file arg: incrementalrelayfee="0.00000010"
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Config file arg: maxconnections="125"
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Config file arg: minrelaytxfee="0.00000000"
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Config file arg: rpcallowip="0.0.0.0/0"
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Config file arg: rpcpassword=****
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Config file arg: rpcport="8332"
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Config file arg: rpcuser=****
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Config file arg: server="1"
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Config file arg: txindex="1"
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Config file arg: zmqpubrawblock="tcp://127.0.0.1:28332"
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Config file arg: zmqpubrawtx="tcp://127.0.0.1:28333"
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Using at most 125 automatic connections (1024 file descriptors available)
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Using 16 MiB out of 16 MiB requested for signature cache, able to store 524288 elements
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Using 16 MiB out of 16 MiB requested for script execution cache, able to store 524288 elements
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z No wallet support compiled in!
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z scheduler thread start
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z WARNING: option -rpcallowip was specified without -rpcbind; this doesn't usually make sense
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Binding RPC on address ::1 port 8332
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Binding RPC on address 127.0.0.1 port 8332
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Config options rpcuser and rpcpassword will soon be deprecated. Locally-run instances may remove rpcuser to use cookie-based auth, or may be replaced with rpcauth. Please see share/rpcauth for rpcauth auth generation.
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Starting HTTP server with 4 worker threads
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Using /16 prefix for IP bucketing
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z init message: Loading P2P addresses…
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Loaded 67144 addresses from peers.dat  322ms
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z init message: Loading banlist…
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z SetNetworkActive: true
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z AddLocal(*.*.*.*:8333,4)
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Script verification uses 7 additional threads
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Cache configuration:
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z * Using 2.0 MiB for block index database
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z * Using 56.0 MiB for transaction index database
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z * Using 8.0 MiB for chain state database
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z * Using 384.0 MiB for in-memory UTXO set (plus up to 286.1 MiB of unused mempool space)
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z init message: Loading block index…
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Assuming ancestors of block 000000000000000000026811d149d4d261995ec5b3f64f439a0a10e1a464af9a have valid signatures.
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Setting nMinimumChainWork=000000000000000000000000000000000000000063c4ebd298db40af57541800
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Opening LevelDB in /home/btc_node_data/blocks/index
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Opened LevelDB successfully
2024-05-01T18:49:37Z Using obfuscation key for /home/btc_node_data/blocks/index: 0000000000000000
2024-05-01T18:49:42Z LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file = 4260
2024-05-01T18:49:42Z LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file info: CBlockFileInfo(blocks=38, size=62375251, heights=840791...841661, time=2024-04-25...2024-05-01)
2024-05-01T18:49:42Z Checking all blk files are present...
2024-05-01T18:49:43Z Initializing chainstate Chainstate [ibd] @ height -1 (null)
2024-05-01T18:49:43Z Opening LevelDB in /home/btc_node_data/chainstate
2024-05-01T18:49:43Z Opened LevelDB successfully
2024-05-01T18:49:43Z Using obfuscation key for /home/btc_node_data/chainstate: 28f95d6aa09096aa
2024-05-01T18:49:43Z Loaded best chain: hashBestChain=000000000000000000023b43da4a5fa2ac60433f0d5205af3f0f4aeae872ae65 height=840959 date=2024-04-26T14:07:04Z progress=0.997045
2024-05-01T18:49:43Z Opening LevelDB in /home/btc_node_data/chainstate
2024-05-01T18:49:44Z Opened LevelDB successfully
2024-05-01T18:49:44Z Using obfuscation key for /home/btc_node_data/chainstate: 28f95d6aa09096aa
2024-05-01T18:49:44Z [Chainstate [ibd] @ height 840959 (000000000000000000023b43da4a5fa2ac60433f0d5205af3f0f4aeae872ae65)] resized coinsdb cache to 8.0 MiB
2024-05-01T18:49:44Z [Chainstate [ibd] @ height 840959 (000000000000000000023b43da4a5fa2ac60433f0d5205af3f0f4aeae872ae65)] resized coinstip cache to 384.0 MiB
2024-05-01T18:49:44Z init message: Verifying blocks…
2024-05-01T18:49:44Z Verifying last 6 blocks at level 3
2024-05-01T18:49:44Z Verification progress: 0%
2024-05-01T18:49:44Z Verification progress: 16%
2024-05-01T18:49:44Z Verification progress: 33%
2024-05-01T18:49:44Z Verification progress: 50%
2024-05-01T18:49:45Z Verification progress: 66%
2024-05-01T18:49:45Z Verification progress: 83%
2024-05-01T18:49:45Z Verification progress: 99%
2024-05-01T18:49:45Z Verification: No coin database inconsistencies in last 6 blocks (21785 transactions)
2024-05-01T18:49:45Z  block index            8352ms
2024-05-01T18:49:45Z Opening LevelDB in /home/btc_node_data/indexes/txindex
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z Opened LevelDB successfully
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z Using obfuscation key for /home/btc_node_data/indexes/txindex: 0000000000000000
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z Setting NODE_NETWORK on non-prune mode
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z block tree size = 841662
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z nBestHeight = 840959
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z initload thread start
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z Bound to 127.0.0.1:8334
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z Bound to [::]:8333
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z torcontrol thread start
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z Bound to 0.0.0.0:8333
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z txindex thread start
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z txindex is enabled at height 840959
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z txindex thread exit
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z Loading 0 mempool transactions from disk...
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z Imported mempool transactions from disk: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 expired, 0 already there, 0 waiting for initial broadcast
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z initload thread exit
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z Loaded 2 addresses from "anchors.dat"
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z 2 block-relay-only anchors will be tried for connections.
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z init message: Starting network threads…
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z net thread start
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z dnsseed thread start
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z Waiting 300 seconds before querying DNS seeds.
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z addcon thread start
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z opencon thread start
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z init message: Done loading
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z msghand thread start
2024-05-01T18:49:46Z New block-relay-only v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841672, peer=0
2024-05-01T18:49:47Z New block-relay-only v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841672, peer=1
2024-05-01T18:49:53Z New outbound-full-relay v2 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841672, peer=4
2024-05-01T18:49:54Z New outbound-full-relay v2 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841672, peer=6
2024-05-01T18:49:55Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841672, peer=5
2024-05-01T18:49:56Z New outbound-full-relay v2 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841672, peer=7
2024-05-01T18:49:56Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841672, peer=8
2024-05-01T18:49:56Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841672, peer=9
2024-05-01T18:49:57Z P2P peers available. Skipped DNS seeding.
2024-05-01T18:49:57Z dnsseed thread exit
2024-05-01T18:50:23Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841672, peer=18
2024-05-01T18:50:29Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841672, peer=20
2024-05-01T18:50:41Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841672, peer=22
2024-05-01T18:50:42Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841672, peer=24
2024-05-01T18:51:12Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841672, peer=37
2024-05-01T18:51:14Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841672, peer=36
2024-05-01T18:51:57Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841673, peer=44
2024-05-01T18:52:30Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841673, peer=46
2024-05-01T18:52:31Z New outbound-full-relay v2 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841673, peer=47
2024-05-01T18:52:36Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70015, blocks=841672, peer=48

more logs:
2024-05-02T06:34:11Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 42220 seconds ago)
2024-05-02T06:34:18Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841740, peer=5299
2024-05-02T06:34:19Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841740, peer=5300
2024-05-02T06:34:26Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841740, peer=5301
2024-05-02T06:34:32Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841740, peer=5304
2024-05-02T06:35:50Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841740, peer=5313
2024-05-02T06:35:55Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841740, peer=5316
2024-05-02T06:35:55Z New block-relay-only v2 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841740, peer=5317
2024-05-02T06:36:01Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70015, blocks=841740, peer=5320
2024-05-02T06:36:02Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70015, blocks=841740, peer=5321
2024-05-02T06:36:33Z New block-relay-only v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841740, peer=5329
2024-05-02T06:36:39Z New block-relay-only v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841740, peer=5331
2024-05-02T06:36:50Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841740, peer=5333
2024-05-02T06:37:17Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841740, peer=5337
2024-05-02T06:37:40Z New block-relay-only v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841740, peer=5338
2024-05-02T06:37:47Z New block-relay-only v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841740, peer=5340
2024-05-02T06:37:59Z New block-relay-only v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841740, peer=5343
2024-05-02T06:38:45Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841740, peer=5350
2024-05-02T06:39:13Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841740, peer=5352
2024-05-02T06:42:57Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70015, blocks=841740, peer=5377
2024-05-02T06:44:12Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841742, peer=5387
2024-05-02T06:44:23Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841742, peer=5389
2024-05-02T06:44:41Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 42850 seconds ago)
2024-05-02T06:44:41Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841742, peer=5391
2024-05-02T06:45:12Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841742, peer=5394
2024-05-02T06:45:14Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841742, peer=5395
2024-05-02T06:46:35Z New outbound-full-relay v1 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=841742, peer=5402

getchaintips
bitcoin-cli getchaintips
[
  {
    "height": 841661,
    "hash": "00000000000000000000d60f130278fd774a1f23ee464a8e1e0c65825f6eea44",
    "branchlen": 702,
    "status": "invalid"
  },
  {
    "height": 840959,
    "hash": "000000000000000000023b43da4a5fa2ac60433f0d5205af3f0f4aeae872ae65",
    "branchlen": 0,
    "status": "active"
  }
]

I think this is invalid block, because confirmation is -1
bitcoin-cli getblockheader 00000000000000000001b3fed517aeb14ff7dc5c912b0421f992df736e1e64eb
{
  "hash": "00000000000000000001b3fed517aeb14ff7dc5c912b0421f992df736e1e64eb",
  "confirmations": -1,
  "height": 840960,
  "version": 538968064,
  "versionHex": "20200000",
  "merkleroot": "8b0d86f2899db4e75f0cf5edc0719b1e960b5d4d7b49bd44b534545bd01fd8a7",
  "time": 1714141213,
  "mediantime": 1714136822,
  "nonce": 3982507624,
  "bits": "170331db",
  "difficulty": 88104191118793.16,
  "chainwork": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000766441ee76e56bdd0ec5e25e",
  "nTx": 3728,
  "previousblockhash": "000000000000000000023b43da4a5fa2ac60433f0d5205af3f0f4aeae872ae65"
}

I tried:
rebuilding bitcoin node
make clean
make
make install

I tried:
bitcoin-cli reconsiderblock 00000000000000000001b3fed517aeb14ff7dc5c912b0421f992df736e1e64eb


Does this device use either an SD card or a USB harddrive to store the blockchain?

Its using hdd. Im running node on server.

I think Murch was interested whether the HDD was connected using USB, SATA or something else.  You should be able to upgrade bitcoind without needing to redownload the blockchain.

I assume its over SATA. I cannot physically access the server. Its hosted: hetzner.com

Can you give the output of the getchaintips command?

@SetasSan Is this your own hardware (hosted at hetzner), or a VPS you rent from them?

@AntoinePoinsot I have updated my post, there is data from getchaintips.

@PieterWuille Its dedicated server. I was running my node ~4-5 years. And it started giving me issues now. It could be that my server hardware is  faulty, I dont know. I think I will be not able to run bitcoin node anymore.
I switched my LND to neutrino.

Yeah it does sound a lot like a hardware failure. Your node rejected the main chain.
